# How to maintain same colour for conditional values across plots?

Tags: r

I'm making several plots where I plot the 10 bacterial species for each plant species and I am colouring the bars based on family the bacteria belong to. While I can do this fine, I want to keep the colours the same across families across plots because later I want to combine them into a multi-faceted figure, and it would make sense to showcase bacterial genera belonging to the same family coloured the same.

Here is an example of my data and code:

```
dput(top10_cintybus)
  structure(list(Order = c("Enterobacterales", "Enterobacterales", 
"Enterobacterales", "Sphingomonadales", "Enterobacterales", "Bacillales", 
"Hyphomicrobiales", "Bacillales", "Xanthomonadales", "Hyphomicrobiales"
), Family = c("Enterobacteriaceae", "Erwiniaceae", "Yersiniaceae", 
"Sphingomonadaceae", "Morganellaceae", "Bacillaceae", "Methylobacteriaceae", 
"Bacillaceae", "Xanthomonadaceae", "Rhizobiaceae"), MKC132 = c(0L, 
0L, 27L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MKC146 = c(33L, 8L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MKC227 = c(11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 
2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L), MKC231 = c(37L, 0L, 0L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 
0L, 2L, 2L), MKC242 = c(0L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), MKC276 = c(9L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MKC351 = c(6L, 
19L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Total = c(96, 34, 34, 20, 
6, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2), Genus = structure(c(10L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("Allorhizobium", "Xanthomonas", "Bacillus", 
"Methylobacterium", "Heyndrickxia", "Arsenophonus", "Sphingomonas", 
"Pantoea", "Serratia", "???.1"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")

dput(top10_alappa)
 structure(list(Order = c("Enterobacterales", "Xanthomonadales", 
"Enterobacterales", "Enterobacterales", "Enterobacterales", "Enterobacterales", 
"Enterobacterales", "Hyphomicrobiales", "Enterobacterales", "Burkholderiales"
), Family = c("Erwiniaceae", "Xanthomonadaceae", "Enterobacteriaceae", 
"Erwiniaceae", "Enterobacteriaceae", "Enterobacteriaceae", "Enterobacteriaceae", 
"Rhizobiaceae", "Morganellaceae", "Oxalobacteraceae"), MKC154 = c(11L, 
0L, 36L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MKC167A = c(14105L, 0L, 
5810L, 13055L, 1223L, 2316L, 1276L, 0L, 550L, 13L), MKC167B = c(18L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MKC214 = c(83842L, 5L, 22936L, 
175L, 6828L, 94L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L), MKC226 = c(0L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MKC233 = c(55L, 0L, 13L, 14L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MKC314 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), MKC364 = c(32L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), MKC366 = c(38L, 
46599L, 0L, 10L, 62L, 0L, 0L, 549L, 0L, 512L), Total = c(98101, 
46612, 28806, 13257, 8113, 2410, 1276, 556, 550, 525), Genus = structure(10:1, levels = c("Janthinobacterium", 
"Morganella", "Allorhizobium", "Citrobacter", "Siccibacter", 
"Enterobacter", "Erwinia", "???.1", "Stenotrophomonas", "Pantoea"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

My code to plot a figure for one of these dataframes as an example. I can colour the bars by Family but I want a way to keep the families same across datasets if possible. Note, "Family" is a factor column.

```
species="Cintybus"
ggplot(data=top10_cintybus,aes(x=Genus, y=Total, fill=Family)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour="black") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans="log10", limits=c(1,1000000), labels=scales::comma,
                     expand=expansion(mult=c(0,.05))) +
  #theme(text=element_text(size=18)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=18)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour="black", face="bold", size=15)) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size=18, vjust=2.5)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold.italic", colour="black", size=15)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=format(Total, big.mark=",")), hjust=1.5, 
            color="white", fontface="plain", size=5) +
  xlab("Genus") + ylab("Abundance") +
  ggtitle(species) + theme(plot.title = element_text(size=18))
```

[image]

And here is an image if I run the above code for the other dataframe.

[image]

As an example, "Pantoea" belongs to the Erwiniaceae family but that family has a different colour in the legend in both figures. I would like to avoid writing our a long list where I manually add a colour to each family because in some other datasets I have 100s of families, and the top 10 will have a mix across datasets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a word of caution: since you have hundreds of families in all, the union of families for all the "top 10s" will likely be a pretty high number too. Each of these will need a unique color, and it will be very hard to distinguish among these. (Even 10 colors for a categorical variable, as with your example data, is pushing it).

That said...

Since you mentioned you'll ultimately be making a faceted plot anyway, the simplest solution may be to use `facet_wrap()`, which will generate a consistent combined legend. With an assist from `tidytext::reorder_within()` and `scale_x_reordered()` to keep your y axes nicely sorted:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidytext)

bind_rows(Alappa = top10_alappa, Cintybus = top10_cintybus, .id = "Species") %>% 
  mutate(Genus = reorder_within(Genus, by = Total, within = Species)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Genus, y=Total, fill=Family)) + 
  geom_col(colour="black") +   # note geom_col() is equivalent to geom_bar(stat = "identity")
  geom_text(aes(label=format(Total, big.mark=",")), hjust=1.5, 
            color="white", fontface="plain", size=5) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_reordered() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans="log10", limits=c(1,1000000), labels=scales::comma,
                     expand=expansion(mult=c(0,.05))) +
  facet_wrap(vars(Species), scales = "free", ncol = 1) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(   # note you can put all your arguments in a single theme() call
    axis.title.x = element_text(size=18),
    axis.text.x = element_text(colour="black", face="bold", size=15),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size=18, vjust=2.5), 
    axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold.italic", colour="black", size=15)
  ) +
  xlab("Genus") + ylab("Abundance")
```

[image]

An alternative approach is to use `scale_fill_manual()` to assign colors to each possible value. Since you may have a lot of values, you can automate this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

families <- list(top10_alappa, top10_cintybus) |>
  lapply(\(dat) dat$Family) |> 
  unlist() |>
  unique() |>
  sort()

family_pal <- viridis_pal(option = "H")(length(families)) 
names(family_pal) <- families
```

Then add `scale_fill_manual(values = family_pal)` to your original code for each plot, which yields:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Create a character vector of colors where the names are from the column in your data that has the values you want to colored consistently, and make sure that vector contains all the possible values. Ex:

```
 MyColors <- c(Enterobacteriaceae = "#333333",
          Erwiniaceae = "#8B8378",
          Yersiniaceae = "#CD2626", 
          Sphingomonadaceae = "#FF8C00",
          Morganellaceae = "#00CD00", 
          Bacillaceae = "#43CD80", 
          Methylobacteriaceae = "#5F9EA0", 
          Bacillaceae = "#1874CD", 
          Xanthomonadaceae = "#27408B", 
          Rhizobiaceae = "#68228B")
```

Then, when you create your ggplot2 graph, call on those colors with scale_fill_manual.

```
 scale_fill_manual(values = MyColors)
```

You can use the same approach for pretty much all the ggplot2 aesthetics, so you use the same approach for line types or point shapes, for example.

Comment: Doesn't work with my code, appending the scale_color_manual doesn't do anything.

Comment: Oh, my mistake: scale_fill_manual.